# Concatenate one NSMutableArray to the end of another NSMutableArray

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nsmutablearray

A simple answer to this super simple question would be great! Here is the pseudcode:

```
NSMutableArray *Africa = [Lion, Tiger, Zebra];
NSMutableArray *Canada = [Polar Bear, Beaver , Loon];

NSMutableArray *Animals = *Africa + *Canada;
```

What I want to end up with:

```
Animals = [Lion, Tiger, Zebra, Polar Bear, Beaver, Loon];
```

What is the proper syntax to achieve this in Objective-C/ Cocoa?

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 49, accepted):

To create an array:

```
NSMutableArray* africa = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects: @"Lion", @"Tiger", @"Zebra", nil];
NSMutableArray* canada = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects: @"Polar bear", @"Beaver", @"Loon", nil];
```

To combine two arrays you can initialize array with elements of the 1st array and then add elements from 2nd to it:

```
NSMutableArray* animals = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:africa];
[animals addObjectsFromArray: canada];
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on Vladimir's answer I wrote a simple function:

```
NSMutableArray* arrayCat(NSArray *a, NSArray *b)
{
    NSMutableArray *ret = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:[a count] + [b count]];
    [ret addObjectsFromArray:a];
    [ret addObjectsFromArray:b];
    return ret;
}
```

but I haven't tried to find out if this approach is faster or slower than Vladimir's